# Unable to load model from controller in linux server in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have developed a small accounting application which running fine in xampp in windows machine and also it is working fine in my development server (linux based).

But, when i migrate the total application to client linux server I got the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/orcilia/public_html/cfm/application/models/sm_main.php on line 1

I have checked it several times but unable to found an error ...

But, I think in the client server there is some issue in case of loading model from controller..

PLEASE HELP ME REGARDING THIS..i have spent a lot of time but unable to get rid of this error...

Thanks,

---

TANAY GHOSH

Comment: could you show your model code which is returning error..?

Comment: can you provide some code please for god sake,how would we know what is the problem.

Comment: Can you please paste the code ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `<?` as an opening tag (check at the very start of your file), change it to 
`<?php`. The server might not allow the shorthand style.